# React JS maps through wrong props

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, react-router, react-redux

so i am fetching two types of keywords from my API, on the one hand the keywords (which the user will be able to add) and allowed keywords. I have made the actions and reducers so far, but when i am mapping through the keywords props it also maps the allowed keyword somehow and i do not understand why... I can't see any problems, maybe I'm missing something and i cant see any connections between keywords and allowed keywords.

So here is the code.
The Keyword Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { keywords, auth } from '../actions';

class Keyword extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchKeywords();
        this.props.fetchAllowedKeywords();
    }
    render() {
        if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            return (
                    <div> 
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {this.props.keywords.map((keyword) => (
                            <span key={`keyword_${keyword.id}`} className="btn btn-primary text-light">{keyword.keyword}</span> //I dont know why, but it displays also the allowed_keywords
                        ))} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
        } else if(!this.props.auth.isLoading) {
            return <p> Please login to customize your news feed. </p>
        }

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        keywords: state.keywords,
        allowed_keywords: state.allowed_keywords,
        user: state.auth.user,
        auth: state.auth,
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchKeywords: () => {
            dispatch(keywords.fetchKeywords());
        },
        fetchAllowedKeywords: () => {
            dispatch(keywords.fetchAllowedKeywords());
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Keyword);
```

the actions:

```
export const fetchKeywords = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    let {token} = getState().auth

    if (token) {
      headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`
    }

    return fetch('/api/keywords/', {headers })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status < 500) {
          return res.json().then(data => {
            return {status: res.status, data}
          })
        } else {
          console.log('Server Error!')
          throw res
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          return dispatch({type: 'FETCH_KEYWORDS', keywords: res.data})
        } else if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
          dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR', data: res.data})
          throw res.data
        }
      })
  }
}

export const fetchAllowedKeywords = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    let {token} = getState().auth

    if (token) {
      headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`
    }

    return fetch('/api/allowedkeywords/', {headers })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status < 500) {
          return res.json().then(data => {
           return {status: res.status, data}
          })
        } else {
          console.log('Server Error!')
          throw res
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          return dispatch({type: 'FETCH_ALLOWEDKEYWORD', allowed_keywords: 
          res.data})
        } else if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
          dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR', data: res.data})
          throw res.data
        }
      })
  }
}
```

and the reducers:

```
const initialState = []

export default function keywords (state = initialState, action) {
  // let keywordList = state.slice();

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_KEYWORDS':
        return [...state, ...action.keywords]

    case 'FETCH_ALLOWEDKEYWORD':
        return [...state, ...action.allowed_keywords]

    default:
      return state
  }
 }
```

I hope you guys could help me and i think i made a stupid mistake so please be indulgent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both type of keyword are mapped in single reducers `keywords`.

There is no way to differentiate these two type of keywords.

```
case 'FETCH_KEYWORDS':
        return [...state, ...action.keywords]

    case 'FETCH_ALLOWEDKEYWORD':
        return [...state, ...action.allowed_keywords]
```

In mapStateToProps,
***It will fetch both type of keyword as mapped to single state.***

```
keywords: state.keywords, //will fetch all keywords
```

Its better if you mapped these keyword in diff keys within same reducers.

```
case 'FETCH_KEYWORDS':
    return {...state, keywords:[...state.keywords,...action.keywords]}

case 'FETCH_ALLOWEDKEYWORD':
    return [...state, allowed_keywords:{...state.allowed_keywords,action.allowed_keywords]}
```

**In mapStateToProps,**

```
keywords: state.keywords.keywords,
allowed_keywords: state.keywords.allowed_keywords
```

EDIT:

Add

```
initialState = {
  keywords: [],
 allowed_keywords : []
}
```

Comment: Hello in this case i get a syntax error https://gyazo.com/5b8aab9d7ca8cc4d3966c8d1aa6b3158

Comment: Need to add initial state

Comment: I did, still syntax error: https://gyazo.com/093ed660caca7bdc1b59f80f4b656adc and https://gyazo.com/a2932d74f7e38c3d9f779dfbc2b31796

Comment: ok i got it, it should be curled brackets, now its working! Thanks Riyaj!

Comment: my bad.Missed unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I've only a theoretical understanding of Redux and reducers.

Your reducer seems to be just returning an `array` and not the state representation/mutation. As per the official [documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-more-actions), I think it should be:

```
const initialState =  {
    keywords: [],
    allowed_keywords: [],
    user: null,
    auth: {},
 }

export default function keywords (state = initialState, action) {
// let keywordList = state.slice();

   switch (action.type) {
      case 'FETCH_KEYWORDS':
       return Object.assign({}, state, {keywords: [...keywords]})

      case 'FETCH_ALLOWEDKEYWORD':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {allowed_keywords: [...keywords]})

      default:
        return state
    }
}
```